# Netbeans C GCC using C99

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, c99

I went to `Netbeans > Preferences > C/C++ > Build Tools` and changed my `C Comiler:` from `usr/bin/gcc` to `usr/bin/c99` so that I could have a local variable in a for loop declared when the for loop is first encountered.

I still get an error...

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/barchart
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d"
c99    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.c
c99: illegal option -- M
usage: c99 [-cEgs] [-D name[=value]] [-I directory] ... [-L directory] ...
       [-o outfile] [-O optlevel] [-U name]... [-W 64] operand ...
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 432ms)
```

I know my code isn't screwing up because it's just a simple for loop in the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    
    return (0);
}
```

I have read the questions on stack overflow where people have repeatedly asked how to do this. Most respond by saying `"Add -std=c99 to your command line"`. Netbeans allows you to do this in the C `Build Tools` menu, but it didn't work for me. (Before that I tried to change my MakeFile, but that didn't work either). I finally tried to change my C interpreter as I stated above so that it points to the `C99` C interpreter, but that didn't work either.

This shouldn't be so hard. Is there a solution that anyone has found that works (at *least* in Netbeans)?

## Note:

I fixed this by using CLang (which I didn't even know I had). I don't know how well it performs in comparison to GCC, but I do know that it (hopefully) uses C99. It's still in the same target directory (`/usr/bin/`) so `/usr/bin/CLang` points to the CLang compiler... and `/usr/bin/CLang++` is the one for - you guessed it - C++. If I have any problems with CLang, I'll probably post below so that people can determine if they want to use it, but at first glance... **I can use a local variable in a for loop; yay!**

From what I just read, however, GCC is compatible with more programming platforms (C/C++, java, etc), but CLang is faster and uses less memory: I got this from [here](http://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html)

Comment: I'm half tempted to open gcc in text editor search for the first occurrence of C89 and replace it with C99.

Comment: There's a simply way of getting `gcc` to accept later standards: The `-std` argument. Like e.g. `gcc -std=c99 ...`. You might want to study the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for your version of GCC.

Comment: I always get a `/usr/bin/make invalid option` when I do that...

Comment: I don't use Netbeans, but it seems to me that either you're putting the option in the wrong place, or your GCC installation is wrong. `gcc` is really the GNU C compiler? What operating system are you on?

Comment: what is `/usr/bin/c99`? Judging by your output it isn't a flavour of GCC.

Comment: Well!!! I did a `Restore Default` in the `Preferences > C/C++ > Build Tools part` (Netbeans 8.0), and it found another C compiler that I didn't even know I had called `CLang`. It's in `/usr/bin` just like GNU, but I guess it works better and utilizes C99 because I can but a local variable in a for loop now. I don't understand why GNU wouldn't just use C99. I would not have been able to cope had I not figured this out or found CLang because I am coming from Java... So I **NEED** that `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {}`. Just kidding; I don't really need it, but I'm familiar with it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg and Matt McNabb...

I'm on a Mac, so it is GNU; the gcc interpreter refers to different flavors of C (it is set up to use C88 when you install it, but you can set the CFlags variable or whatever it is supposed to be called to refer to C99 instead of C98 so you can use a local variable in a loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the C Standard like this:

Open **`project properties -> Build -> C Compiler -> C Standard`** and set `C99` there.

The `C Standard` should contain Standard, C89, C99 and C11 on a current NetBeans / compiler.

**Don't change the compiler!**

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project Properties, then Build -> C Compiler -> Additional Options, and add -std=c99.  Like this:

[image: NetBeans Project Properties with -std=c99]

Your compiler should remain as /usr/bin/gcc (hopefully you have a new enough version!).

Comment: I tried that (before and now) and it always tells me that they are "invalid options":
    `/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- =
    /usr/bin/make: invalid option -- c
    /usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 9
    /usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 9
    Usage: make [options] [target] ...
    Options:`

Comment: I have found a C99 executable in the `/usr/bin/` dir, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @John Zwinck: What version of NB are you using? This dialog should contain a combobox where you can select the C/C++ standard and many other settings.

Comment: I borrowed that screenshot from another post.  I agree that NetBeans' latest versions have more options.

Comment: @ollo Sorry, I'm using Netbeans 8.0

Comment: @Dylan: With NB 8 you have those settings - mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry; I know I am answering my own question, but I think this is valid because I got it setup on Mac os x with Clang, but I could not replicate this on Windows, and I still could not get `-std=c99` to work. So, here is my solution.

A `.c` file can run in any properly configured C++ interpreter. Therefore, in order to allow C99 implementation, you can simply make the path to the "C" compiler, the path to a C++ compiler.

For example, use `g++` instead of `gcc`. If you are in Netbeans 8.0, simply go to the `options (windows)/preferences (mac) > C/C++ > Build Tools` and change the `cc` in `gcc` to `++`.

Done. At least it worked for me.

If you're doing this though, you should probably just create a `.cpp` file.

Comment: In other words: If you want to use C99, use C++ instead!? o.O

Comment: This is incorrect. C and C++ are two different languages, and there are plenty of valid C programs that are not valid C++. C99 supports variable length arrays, which C++ does not. If you want to compile C99, use a C99 compiler (`gcc -std=c99`, or `clang -std=c99`, or `c99`, which is typically a small wrapper around gcc or clang).

Comment: @KeithThompson I understand. The only problem is that I'm not sure how to run Netbeans8.0 with switches like that. I have never seen a C program that is not compilable via a C++ compiler, and - for my purposes - it worked. I probably should have been working in C++ anyway. So the moral of this story is just use C++.